# Paging error in my mvc 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have error on my asp.net MVC 5 controller. I have the following code on it:

**Controller**

**Index Action**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string Seach_Data, string findby, int? page, string currentFilter)
    {
        if (findby == "fname")
        {
            HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
            {
                data = new List<Heads>()
            };
            var AllHeads = db.Heads;
            foreach (var item in AllHeads)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    list.data.Add(new Heads
                    {
                        h_id = item.h_id,
                        fname = item.fname,
                        lname = item.lname,
                    });
                }
            }
            return View(list.Where(x => x.fname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6));
        }
        else if (findby == "lname")
        {
            HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
            {
                data = new List<Heads>()
            };
            var AllHeads = db.Heads;
            foreach (var item in AllHeads)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    list.data.Add(new Heads
                    {
                        h_id = item.h_id,
                        fname = item.fname,
                        lname = item.lname,
                    });
                }
            }
            return View(list.Where(x => x.lname == Seach_Data).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6)); 
        }
              else

        {
            HeadVM list = new HeadVM()
            {
                data = new List<Heads>()
            };
            var AllHeads = db.Heads;
            foreach (var item in AllHeads)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    list.data.Add(new Heads
                    {
                        h_id = item.h_id,
                        fname = item.fname,
                        lname = item.lname,
                    });
                }
            }
            return View(list.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 6)); 

        }
    }
```

i have a problem on my index code i want to search and display panging but im having an error on my return view even before i build. my error says "does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'parishV3.Models.HeadVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Can you include your references from this controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `using System.Linq` in top of your file.